# Is there a way to get an HTML page to "remember" which button was pressed on a previous page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page with three buttons and I'd like to be able to "remember" which button was pressed on a later page. The sequence of events goes something like this:

1. page1.html: "Please click a button." BUTTON 1, BUTTON 2, BUTTON 3
2. page2.html: "Thanks for clicking a button. click for next page."
3. page3.html: "You selected BUTTON (x) from page 1."

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Simple solutions would be: cookies, sessions or GET parameters

Comment: Or use sessions if you use php, as your tags state ;)

Comment: @JohannesLumpe I was browsing the javascript section, didn't notice the php tag. :P Yes, sessions could be an easier way around that.

Comment: thanks everyone for your super-fast replies. so i need to use php sessions... this should be easy enough, i hope.

Comment: @fabricio no offense intended :)

Comment: @JohannesLumpe Both ways work, so I don't see any problem, you're just contributing as everyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use cookies.

PHP:

```
setcookie(name,value,expiration);
```

I think you are looking for a tutorial on how to doing this, a great website to get started is  [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: @qwertymk No one goes there for a shit certificate, its just a good resource for getting started as the things are easy to understand for new comers

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt

php.net is better for new comers (like me) :) I am victim of w3schools. May be soul rest in peace :P

Comment: @Jashwant I started when I was 13, I found php.net to be horrible and w3schools to help me out just the way I liked. I could find the thnigs I needed to get started and soon I was toying around with everything I could lay my hands on. Now google is my reference guide and yes usually that loads to a php.net page.

Comment: You started too early for my country :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a form on each page and use hidden inputs to remember anything you want from a previous page, by using a little bit of javascript. Here is the principle (untested), modify for your own case:

```
<form name='session_form' action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='button_name' value=''>
</form>

<input type='button' name='button1' value='BUTTON 1' onClick='go(this);'>
<input type='button' name='button2' value='BUTTON 2' onClick='go(this);'>
<input type='button' name='button3' value='BUTTON 3' onClick='go(this);'>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function go(button) {
        var f = document.forms.form_session;
        var bname = button.name;
        f.button_name.value = bname;
        f.action = 'page' + bname[-1] + '.php';
        f.submit();
    }

// or if you have loaded jQuery, drop the `onClick` attribute and use something like this:
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(e) {
       var bname = $(this).attr('name');
       $('input[name=button_name]').val(bname);
       var action = 'page' + bname[-1] + '.php';
       $('form[name=session_form]').attr('action', action).submit();
    });
</script>
```

In PHP (server-side) you can then read the name of the clicked button using `$_POST["button_name"]`.